# Exchange authorization code with access code

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

I've got a problems with the Web API Authorization guide of Spotify. 
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

I've done step 1 to 3 with no problem. But then in step 4."Your application requests refresh and access tokens" there are following parameters you need to exchange token.
1) grant_type
2) code
3) redirect_uri

header parameter:
1) Authorization: Basic

If i'm right 1) grant_type is the code you get from the step 3 "Callback" (http://example.com/callback?code=#thecode), but where do I get the 2)code from?

Comment: I interpret it wrong way in the documentation. 
1)  grant_type 
Required. As defined in the OAuth 2.0 specification, this field must contain the value "**authorization_code**". I think they mean it has to be a string that said "authorization_code"

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys, I've solved it already.

For step 4 "Your application requests refresh and access tokens" following was done:

setup a POST-request ofcourse,in my case it was PHP with the framework Cakephp.

Parameters that needs to be filled are :

1. grant_type="**authorization_code**"
2. code="**the code you get from the callback (http://ex.com/callback*?code=#thecode*)**"
3. redirect_uri="**the uri you've saved in** https://developer.spotify.com/my-applications/#!/application "

Header parameters:

I've used the alternative method. 
The client_id and the client_secret I've sended throught the POST-body.